# how to use context and still use metadata api inside next js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am unable to render `layout.tsx` with a default theme as the theme provider is needed and useContext is called. Therefore next js complains about not being able to run server-side. So I put the `use client` field into the document, and now the metadata tags won't load.

layout.tsx

```
'use client'

import { Metadata } from 'next'
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: {
    default: 'some title',
    template: '%s | some title'
  }
}

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
const theme = createTheme({...
```

## ...

```
export default ({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) => (

    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <html>
                <body>{children}</body>
            </html>
        </LocalizationProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not make your layout a client component, rather create a client component called Provider that then can be imported in your layout. Heres an example:

```
"use client";

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'

interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {}

const theme = createTheme(/* ... */);

export default function Provider({ children }: Props) {
  return <ThemeProvider>{ children }</ThemeProvider>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split them in 2 files simple, one client & another server

Layout.tsx

```
import { Metadata } from 'next'

import RootLayout from './RootLayout'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: {
    default: 'some title',
    template: '%s | some title'
  }
}

export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <RootLayout>{children}</RootLayout>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

RootLayout.tsx

```
'use client'

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
const theme = createTheme({})

export default RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) => (

    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <html>
                <body>{children}</body>
            </html>
        </LocalizationProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
)
```